# SceneKit Swift - using HDR environment light map from file

Tags: swift, scenekit, hdr, openexr

I'm trying to use a spherical HDR image as the environment light in a Swift project using SceneKit and am having trouble using standard 32bpc HDR imaging formats to do it. I can use PNG maps easily, but have trouble loading images from an OpenEXR .exr or Radiance .hdr file.

In [this documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration/3175416-wantshdrenvironmenttextures?language=objc) it seems to describe the feature I'm after.

I can't find any apple documentation describing it, so my current best guess is to write my own function to load the files and then create a CGImage instance using a custom CGDataProvider, as it seems that this container supports [floating point](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgbitmapinfo/1455087-floatcomponents) and [high dynamic range values](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcolorspace/3325503-ishdr). Then set that CGImage as the content of the environment light.

Is anyone able to confirm if this is the right idea or if this *is* actually already implemented somewhere. 
I've not done any apple development before (come from a graphics background) and am not sure if I'm on a bit of a wild goose chase at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What "troubles" do you have exactly? `scene.lightingEnvironment.contents = "envmap.exr"` should work.

Comment: aahhhh, that did it! turns out it was an issue with how I was loading the file in the first place, it wasn't included as a build resource. Like I said: new at this, haha.
What I thought was happening was that UIImage couldn't handle it. I'd better do some more research.